# Efficient mechanism to generate operator overload functions

Tags: c++, macros

I'm attempting to tidy up a C++ framework (PyCXX).

One particular file contains ~400 lines of operator overload functions, which I've managed to reduce to the following:

```
#define OP( op, l, r, cmpL, cmpR ) \
    bool operator op( l, r ) { return cmpL op cmpR; }

#define OPS( l, r, cmpL, cmpR ) \
    OP( !=, l, r, cmpL, cmpR ) \
    OP( ==, l, r, cmpL, cmpR ) \
    OP( > , l, r, cmpL, cmpR ) \
    OP( >=, l, r, cmpL, cmpR ) \
    OP( < , l, r, cmpL, cmpR ) \
    OP( <=, l, r, cmpL, cmpR )

    OPS( const Long &a, const Long &b,   a.as_long() , b.as_long() )
    OPS( const Long &a,       int   b,   a.as_long() , b           )
    OPS( const Long &a,       long  b,   a.as_long() , b           )
    OPS( int         a, const Long &b,   a           , b.as_long() )
    OPS( long        a, const Long &b,   a           , b.as_long() )

#ifdef HAVE_LONG_LONG
    OPS( const Long &a, PY_LONG_LONG b,   a.as_long_long() , b                )
    OPS( PY_LONG_LONG a, const Long &b,   a                , b.as_long_long() )
#endif

    //------------------------------------------------------------
    // compare operators
    OPS( const Float &a, const Float &b,   a.as_double() , b.as_double() )
    OPS( const Float &a, double       b,   a.as_double() , b             )
    OPS( double a,       const Float &b,   a             , b.as_double() )

}    // end of namespace Py
```

However, I wonder if it may be possible to tidy it up further.

It looks as though I can save having to pass all the parameters each time by using:

```
#define OPS( ... ) \
    OP( !=, ##__VA_ARGS__ ) \
    OP( ==, ##__VA_ARGS__ ) \
    OP( > , ##__VA_ARGS__ ) \
    OP( >=, ##__VA_ARGS__ ) \
    OP( < , ##__VA_ARGS__ ) \
    OP( <=, ##__VA_ARGS__ )
```

Although I have a hunch this might be making the code less transparent.

Another possible idea would involve storing pairs:

```
#define FD(op, x) (       Float &x , op, x.as_double()    )
#define L1(op, x) ( const Long &x  , op, x.as_long()      )
#define L2(op, x) ( const Long &x  , op, x.as_long_long() )
:
```

but I am risking obfuscation through trying too hard.  I think it is commonly accepted that other things being equal, readability trumps concise.

What other viable design patterns could I consider?

Comment: @glampert, looks like you can't distinguish between member and non-member operators; that's sad.

Comment: Adding 'const' gives: "Non-member function cannot have 'const' qualifier"

Comment: Could you use templates?

Comment: You could use some recursive macros, but I would personally create a script to generate the file from another file (specifying e.g. type; op1,op2,op3; arg1,arg2,arg3 - generator will emit all possible combinations).

Comment: Or try [Barton–Nackman trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barton%E2%80%93Nackman_trick) if you can alter the classes (some variadic templates could solve all your friend-operators).

Comment: @Griwes, people make mistakes, no need to be rude about it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was looking a bit at your PyCXX and want to offer you [Barton–Nackman trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barton%E2%80%93Nackman_trick) using [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) together with variadic template recursion (through partial specialization). **This way you can solve all your types and conversion operators with one template:**

```
template<typename T> struct Arithmetic;
using Long = Arithmetic<long long>;
using Double = Arithmetic<long double>;

template<class Base, class... Other> struct compare_operators {};

template<class Base, class First, class... Other>
  struct compare_operators<Base, First, Other...>
  : compare_operators<Base, Other...>
{
    friend bool operator == (const Base& a, First b) {
        return a.template as<First>() == b; }
    friend bool operator != (const Base& a, First b) {
        return a.template as<First>() != b; }
    friend bool operator <  (const Base& a, First b) {
        return a.template as<First>() <  b; }
    friend bool operator <= (const Base& a, First b) {
        return a.template as<First>() <= b; }
    friend bool operator >  (const Base& a, First b) {
        return a.template as<First>() >  b; }
    friend bool operator >= (const Base& a, First b) {
        return a.template as<First>() >= b; }

    friend bool operator == (const Base& a, const Arithmetic<First>& b) {
        return a.template as<First>() == b.value; }
    friend bool operator != (const Base& a, const Arithmetic<First>& b) {
        return a.template as<First>() != b.value; }
    friend bool operator <  (const Base& a, const Arithmetic<First>& b) {
        return a.template as<First>() <  b.value; }
    friend bool operator <= (const Base& a, const Arithmetic<First>& b) {
        return a.template as<First>() <= b.value; }
    friend bool operator >  (const Base& a, const Arithmetic<First>& b) {
        return a.template as<First>() >  b.value; }
    friend bool operator >= (const Base& a, const Arithmetic<First>& b) {
        return a.template as<First>() >= b.value; }
};

template<typename T> struct Arithmetic
  : compare_operators<Arithmetic<T>
  , long long, int, short, double, float, long double>
{
    T value;
    Arithmetic(T value): value(value) {}

    template<typename X, typename = enable_if_t<is_arithmetic<decay_t<X>>::value>>
      X as() const { return (X)value; }
};

int main() {
    Long val(3);
    if(val > 2) cout << "val > 2\n";
    if(val <= 3.2) cout << "val <= 3.2\n";
    Double dbl(3.14);
    if(val < dbl) cout << "val < dbl\n";
}
```

Beware that the comparision operators need some fine-tuning especially when you compare integral vs. floating-point (which to choose as common type) and that `dacay_t` in conversion operator may be problematic (not sure). (Finally imagine `using namespace std`, but I use my own header while explicitly using selected std features/classes in the namespace and then using the namespace).

---

BTW: This would be the same (but the `as` conversion is altered) in my own syntax, which you may find a bit familiar:

```
#include "basics.hpp"
using*firda

forward template<typename T> struct Arithmetic
using Long = Arithmetic<long long>
using Double = Arithmetic<long double>

template<class Base, class... Other>
  struct compare_operators

template<class Base, class First, class... Other>
  struct compare_operators<Base, First, Other...>
  : compare_operators<Base, Other...>

    friend bool operator == (const Base& a, First b)
        return a.template as<First>() == b
    friend bool operator != (const Base& a, First b)
        return a.template as<First>() != b
    friend bool operator <  (const Base& a, First b)
        return a.template as<First>() <  b
    friend bool operator <= (const Base& a, First b)
        return a.template as<First>() <= b
    friend bool operator >  (const Base& a, First b)
        return a.template as<First>() >  b
    friend bool operator >= (const Base& a, First b)
        return a.template as<First>() >= b

    friend bool operator == (const Base& a, const Arithmetic<First>& b)
        return a.template as<First>() == b.value
    friend bool operator != (const Base& a, const Arithmetic<First>& b)
        return a.template as<First>() != b.value
    friend bool operator <  (const Base& a, const Arithmetic<First>& b)
        return a.template as<First>() <  b.value
    friend bool operator <= (const Base& a, const Arithmetic<First>& b)
        return a.template as<First>() <= b.value
    friend bool operator >  (const Base& a, const Arithmetic<First>& b)
        return a.template as<First>() >  b.value
    friend bool operator >= (const Base& a, const Arithmetic<First>& b)
        return a.template as<First>() >= b.value

template<typename T> struct Arithmetic
  : compare_operators<Arithmetic<T>
  , long long, int, short, double, float, long double>

    T value
    Arithmetic(T value): value(value) {}

    template<typename X>
      enable_if_t<is_arithmetic<X>::value,
      X> as() const
        return value

int main()
    Long val(3)
    if val > 2; cout << "val > 2\n"
    if val <= 3.2; cout << "val <= 3.2\n"
    Double dbl(3.14)
    if val < dbl; cout << "val < dbl\n"
```

Comment: Barton-Nackman is the way to solve this although I might not agree completely with your implementation.

Comment: @EmilyL.: Feel free to improve it in your own answer :) This is teamwork, I don't care for points but to help people ;)

Comment: That's more time than I have to contribute right now :) But +1 anyways.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I have managed to come up with:

```
#define OP( op, l, r, cmpL, cmpR ) \
    bool operator op( l, r ) { return cmpL op cmpR; }

#define OPS( ... ) \
    OP( !=, ##__VA_ARGS__ ) \
    OP( ==, ##__VA_ARGS__ ) \
    OP( > , ##__VA_ARGS__ ) \
    OP( >=, ##__VA_ARGS__ ) \
    OP( < , ##__VA_ARGS__ ) \
    OP( <=, ##__VA_ARGS__ )

#define BI_( a, b, convA, convB ) \
    OPS(a, b, convA, convB ) \
    OPS(b, a, convB, convA )

    OPS( const Long  &a, const Long  &b  ,  a.as_long()      , b.as_long()    )
    BI_( const Long  &a, int          b  ,  a.as_long()      , b              )
    BI_( const Long  &a, long         b  ,  a.as_long()      , b              )

#ifdef HAVE_LONG_LONG
    BI_( const Long  &a, PY_LONG_LONG b  ,  a.as_long_long() , b              )
#endif

    OPS( const Float &a, const Float &b  ,  a.as_double()    , b.as_double()  )
    BI_( const Float &a, double       b  ,  a.as_double()    , b              )

#undef OP, OPS, BI_
```

I have detailed the thought process here: http://mathpad.wikidot.com/pycxx-operators